# How to query elasticsearch: I keep getting index_not_found_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 6.4.3

Issue: a /_search command returns:

```
index_not_found_exception
```

Specifically:

```
$ curl -X GET "192.168.2.2:9200/MyNew_Index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
"from": 0,
"size": 40,
"sort":
...
```

Returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "index_not_found_exception",
            "reason": "no such index",
            "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
            "resource.id": "MyNew_Index",
            "index_uuid": "_na_",
            "index": "MyNew_Index"
        }],
...
```

But when I look to see what indexes are present, I see it:

```
$ curl -X GET "192.168.2.2:9200/_cat/indices?v" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
health status index                          uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   MyNew_Index 71X8IOLzQaKqj7aaK5CRbA  50   1  900288822
3322978        1tb        533.4gb
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Weird. Try deleting the index and recreating. Maybe also try something lowercase? Can’t see anything different than what I’ve done 1000x

Comment: @JohnH Drop the index... not possible, it is a 500GB index that takes days to build (and it works, just not via curl)

Comment: Did you encounter any memory issues recently with the cluster or any crashes? I faced the same issue once because of storage getting filled up. I have to restart the cluster to query the index. Don't know how, process dumps filled up my complete storage and faced this issue.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri No issues of any kind. The cluster is running cleanly.

Comment: It's a memory issue, but I'm not sure why you are getting it searching only 1 index. I had this error searching many indexes with a lot of data